# Find out when file was added to system or placed in directory

Tags: linux

On Ubuntu: I want to be able to determine when a file was added to the system or in other words when it was placed/copied into the directory. The time stamp is 'last modified' so when one installs from Apt the timestamp is not the same as when it was actually placed on the system. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with `stat`? It provides more info about the file

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inotify`.

From the manpage:
"The inotify API provides a mechanism for monitoring filesystem
       events.  Inotify can be used to monitor individual files, or to
       monitor directories."

Watching for file or directory change can be done with

`int inotify_add_watch(int fd, const char *pathname, uint32_t mask);`

where mask can be IN_MODIFY to see all modifications on the file/directory.